# Cordova Setup Issue: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly

Tags: cordova, ant

I created an android project using `Cordova 5.0.0` and am trying to compile it.  I am using the command: `ant release`

I get the following output:

> Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly. We cannot execute
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/bin/java

So, I changed the `JAVA_HOME` variable in the `.bash_profile` file to the value below as directed on one of these threads:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home
```

I used the echo command to verify that the `JAVA_HOME` variable was set.

I still receive the same output when compiling with ant relase.  It doesn't recognize the change that I made to the value.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: which platform you are using?

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to say it can't execute your java binary.  It's probably the wrong location or the wrong access?

Try typing this in your console to see what type of error you get
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/bin/java

If it's not found, JAVA_HOME is wrong.  The path you are setting JAVA_HOME to is the same JAVA_HOME it's currently using.  It just appends /bin/java for the executable

Comment: The problem is that Ant is looking at a different path than what I have set in the .bash_profile variable.

Comment: If you set your java_home to /javaHome,
When it tries to execute java it'll append /bin/java - /javaHome/bin/java

Comment: It sounds like your path is properly being set, something else might be wrong